# Cant get constructor(value1, value2) { this.value1 = value1 this.value2 = value2 }

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Can anyone explain me what does this code do:

```
constructor(value1, value2) {
    this.value1 = value1
    this.value2 = value2
  }
```

I am new to this language, and this kind of things are strange. In the simplest words, can anyone explain me? Thank you

Comment: MDN (friendlier): [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/constructor). Official [JS documentation](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-static-semantics-constructormethod) (technical).

Answer (score 1):

In ReactJS, the constructor is mainly used to initialize the state or to bind the methods.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
}
```

The constructor has only one parameter which is props. If you are sending some data from the parent element then you will get the value in props.

For example, if you are sending two values `value1` and `value2`. Then in the constructor you can use like

```
constructor({ ...props }) {
    super(props);
    this.value1 = props.value1;
    this.value2 = props.value2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a constructor. It exists inside a class and its purpose is to create class objects. When you call a class constructor, you get a new class object. The `this` inside the constructor refers to the object that is created. `this.value1 = value1` means "create a new property, called value1, on the class object you are creating right now and assign it the value of `value1` (the argument the constructor receives).

A more complete example would be:

```
class Example{

constructor(value1,value2){
this.value1= value1;
this.value2 = value2;
}

}


let myExample = new Example("first value","second value");

console.log(myExample);
```

The output would be a class object with these values:

```
[object Object] {
  value1: "first value",
  value2: "second value"
}
```